# Understanding javascript borrowing methods

Tags: javascript

There is a lot of explanation about how to convert a function's `arguments` to a real array.

But I have found it very interesting when you simplify the code with the help of `bind`.

[MDN Array.prototype.slice - Array-like objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects)

[MDN Function.prototype.bind - Creating shortcuts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Creating_shortcuts)

For example:

```
function list() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}

var list1 = list(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Simplified call:

```
var unboundSlice = Array.prototype.slice;
var slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(unboundSlice);

function list() {
  return slice(arguments);
}

var list1 = list(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2, 3]
```

It is working the same way if you use `apply` instead of `call`:

```
var slice = Function.prototype.apply.bind(unboundSlice);
```

Which can be even shortened by using `call` from any function instance, since is the same as the one in the prototype and same approach with `slice` from an array instance:

```
var slice = alert.call.bind([].slice);
```

You can try

```js
var slice = alert.call.bind([].slice);

function list() {
    console.log(slice(arguments));
}

list(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

So the first very weird thing is coming into my mind is calling `bind` on `apply`, but the first argument of `bind` should be an object (as context) and not a function (`Array.prototype.slice`).

The other is that is working with both `call` and `apply` the same way.

I am writing javascript for quite a long time and using these methods day to day confidently but I can not wrap my head around this.

Maybe I am missing some very fundamental detail.

Could somebody give an explanation?

Comment: Functions are objects.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks, I haven't seen it from this angle

Comment: *"The other is that is working with both call and apply the same way."* - Because both `call()` and `apply()` expect the same thing as their first argument, and in your examples you don't pass any additional arguments.

Comment: @nnnnnn, yes thanks, I know but the interesting part is the rest of the arguments for those methods.
They accept arguments in different formats and in this case they are getting the same, an array-like object as the second argument.
My thoughts are: 'bind' returns either 'call' or 'apply' bound to 'slice' and for returned 'apply' it is clear, it is destructuring the arguments array 
but in the case off 'call' the passed array is wrapped with another arguments array and I don't understand how 'slice' can work on it.
My question is what 'bind' returns?

Comment: On a complete sidenote, about the arguments to array discussion, ES6 introduced the spread (`...`) operator, which makes it even easier: `function list(...args) {
    console.log(args);
}`

Comment: *" in this case they are getting the same, an array-like object as the second argument. My thoughts are: 'bind' returns either 'call' or 'apply' bound to 'slice'"*' - They're  getting the same, array-like `arguments` object as their *first* argument; the first argument to both `call()` and `apply()` is the object that will be `this` within the function they are calling/applying. So `arguments` becomes `this` for `slice()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the first argument of `bind` should be an object (as context)

Yes.

> and not a function (`Array.prototype.slice`).

Why not? For one, all functions are objects, so nothing wrong here.

From another perspective, if you use `slice.call(…)` or `slice.apply(…)` then the `slice` object *is* the context (receiver) of the `call`/`apply` method invocations.

> What is the difference between binding `apply` and `call`?

There is no difference between `applyBoundToSlice(arguments)` and `callBoundToSlice(arguments)`. The difference is `applyBoundToSlice(arguments, [0, n])` vs `callBoundToSlice(arguments, 0, n)` if you want pass start and end arguments to the `slice`.

Comment: Not "context (receiver)" but "target (receiver)"?

Comment: @BenAston: "receiver" is the technically correct term. I see (and write myself) "context" more often though, but I hardly ever see it called "target"

Comment: Ok guys, now I understand. Calling bind on apply was confusing me, I was thinking I set the first argument (partially apply) of the apply method but bind sets the context as the first argument and than you can partially apply the function's arguments.

@Bergi, I accept this one as correct answer

Comment: @Bergi IIUC "target" and "receiver" are effectively synonyms. Both are used in the spec. I agree "context" is used colloquially but I would argue it is less correct because it implies an abbreviation of "execution context", which is something else entirely.

Comment: @BenAston: Actually the spec uses neither "target" nor "receiver" for what we are talking about here. It always refers to it as "thisArg(ument)". Regarding "context", I've never talked about execution contexts colloquially.

Comment: Funny, yesterday I got the Javascript weekly newsletter with the topic of this.

http://davidshariff.com/blog/borrowing-methods-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

One can use call keyword to implement method borrowing. Below example shows method borrowing.

```
var john = {
  name: "John",
  age: 30,
  isAdult: function() {
    console.log(this.name+"'s age is "+this.age);
    if (this.age > 18) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

console.log(john.isAdult());

var rita = {
  name: "Rita",
  age: 15
}

console.log(john.isAdult.call(rita));
```

Observe the last line. How the keyword call is used and how rita object is passed to the function.